# Electron read file from path with offset and length

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, filesystems

Assuming that I am using the latest version of Electron, I need to access the Filesystem-API so that I can read potentially **huge files** (several Gigabytes) **chunk-based**.

I have already implemented a system, so that I could supply an offset and a length to the function. Furthermore an other requirement is that **only a path** can be supplied and not some actual file-object from a file-chooser (otherwise I could use pure JS).

So far I have tried to use the readFile-API (by the way - the data needs to be base64 encoded):

```
window.require('electron').remote.require('fs').readSync(path, {enoding:'base64'}, (err,data)=>{...})
```

The issue with this solution is that I cannot supply the offset/length...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using params of readFileSync instead of readSync

https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readsync_fd_buffer_offset_length_position

```
 fs.open('your-file', 'r', (err, fd) => {
   const data = fs.readSync(fd, buffer, bytesRead, size, bytesRead)
 })
```